# Angular currency converter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Do anyone know how can I make the code I stated below to work on Angular?
I have gotten the code from [here](https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/get-widget/vertical#fis;Humanity;270;;true;SGD-USD;false) and I have tried it on a HTML page and it work but for some reason when I put it in my home.component.html it doesn't work

```
<!--Currency Converter widget by FreeCurrencyRates.com -->

<div id='gcw_mainFQN2uneJb' class='gcw_mainFQN2uneJb'></div>
<a id='gcw_siteFQN2uneJb' href='https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/'>FreeCurrencyRates.com</a>
<script>function reloadFQN2uneJb(){ var sc = document.getElementById('scFQN2uneJb');if (sc) sc.parentNode.removeChild(sc);sc = document.createElement('script');sc.type = 'text/javascript';sc.charset = 'UTF-8';sc.async = true;sc.id='scFQN2uneJb';sc.src = 'https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/widget-vertical-editable?iso=SGDUSD&df=2&p=FQN2uneJb&v=fis&source=fcr&width=270&width_title=0&firstrowvalue=1&thm=E0CFC2,F4F0EC,D49768,CB842E,FFFFFF,E0CFC2,F4F0EC,B85700,000000&title=Currency%20Converter&tzo=-480';var div = document.getElementById('gcw_mainFQN2uneJb');div.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, div);} reloadFQN2uneJb(); </script>
<!-- put custom styles here: .gcw_mainFQN2uneJb{}, .gcw_headerFQN2uneJb{}, .gcw_ratesFQN2uneJb{}, .gcw_sourceFQN2uneJb{} -->
<!--End of Currency Converter widget by FreeCurrencyRates.com -->
```

Comment: Try running `reloadFQN2uneJb();` function once your partial view loaded.

Comment: @Adriani6 do you mean putting it in the index.html?